# cancel package and tables

Tags: mathjax, cancel, strikeout

I have a "friend" who needs to do some kind of strikethrough or cancel but for a whole row or column (or both) of a table at a time.   It should ideally be something supported by MathJax, so various picture packages e.g. tikz aren't what my "friend" is interested in.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

While it requires manual specification of measurements, it has the advantage of working without any special packages or tools.  It amounts to `\rlap`ping `\rule`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
This & is & a \\
\rlap{\rule[2.5pt]{4.5cm}{1pt}}table & built & using\\
the & \rlap{\smash{\makebox[7ex]{\rule[-2pt]{1pt}{35pt}}}}tabular & environment
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the `array` equivalent, since MathJax does not support `tabular`.  Obviously, if the table content is math, the `\mbox` nonsense can be dispensed with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mbox{This} & \mbox{is} & \mbox{a} \\
\rlap{\rule[2.5pt]{4.5cm}{1pt}}\mbox{table} & \mbox{built} & \mbox{using}\\
\mbox{the} & \rlap{\smash{\makebox[7ex]{\rule[-2pt]{1pt}{35pt}}}}\mbox{tabular} & \mbox{environment}
\end{array}
\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting!  But tabular isn't supported by MathJax, I think - any ideas for that?  For instance, could the same thing work in an array environment?

Comment: @kcrisman I don't have familiarity with MathJax, but I do know that `array`  is essentially a math version of `tabular`.  Thus, it is hard to believe that `array` would work in MathJax, but `tabular` not.

Comment: @kcrisman ...but to you direct question, yes, the identical result can be achieved in an `array` environment, allowing of course that all text has to be placed in an `\mbox` to avoid it being set as math.

Comment: The MathJax author has explicitly stated that since it is a text macro, not a math one, it will not be supported.

Comment: @kcrisman I see...where is TextJax when you need it?

Comment: @kcrisman Please see my edit for `array`.

Comment: Nice.  Did I mention MathJax doesn't support `\rule` (but does `\Rule`) or `\makebox`?  (Ducks!)

Comment: @kcrisman How about `\textrm` in lieu of `\mbox`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59317/discussion-between-kcrisman-and-steven-b-segletes).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Steven I have something kludgy but usable in MathJax, I think, especially because my friend will only have numerical input:

```
\begin{array}{ccc}
This & is & a \\
\rlap{\raise{2px}\Rule{6cm}{1pt}{0pt}}table & built & using\\
the & \rlap{\hspace{30px}\smash{{\Rule{1pt}{32pt}{2pt}}}}tabular & environment
\end{array}
```

[image]