# Trying to strike out a column in a matrix (array)

Tags: arrays, strikeout

So using the last answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47730/draw-a-line-through-one-column-of-a-matrix), as I am using an array not any matrix. I am using MathTex for Libre Office Writer. FYI.

Normal Matrix:

[image]

```
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 3 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & -4 \\
1 & -3 & 5
\end{array}
\right]
```

And my Stiked Matrix:

[image]

```
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rowstrike}{%
  \noalign{%
    % normal "baselineskip" in tabular is height + depth of \@arstrutbox
    \vskip-.5\dimexpr\ht\@arstrutbox+\dp\@arstrutbox\relax
    % default line thickness is 0.4pt
    \vskip-.2pt\relax
    \hrule
    \vskip-.2pt\relax
    \vskip+.5\dimexpr\ht\@arstrutbox+\dp\@arstrutbox\relax
  }%
}
\newcommand{\colstrike}{%
  @{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}|@{\hspace{-.5\tabcolsep}}c@{}@{\hspace{1.5\tabcolsep}}
}
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}\colstrike cc}
3 & 3 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & ^-4 \\ \rowstrike
1 & ^-3 & 5
\end{array}
\right]
```

The problem is in my Column strike through, the alignment of the second row is messed up. I would like to modify my macro so as to have a single command to strike any column, of any size (if possible). <s>And, to fix the alignment.</s> Got the alignment to work by altering:

```
@{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}|@{\hspace{-.5\tabcolsep}}c@{}
```

to:

```
@{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}|@{\hspace{-.5\tabcolsep}}c@{}@{\hspace{1.5\tabcolsep}}
```

[image]

But it only works for a single number, any more and this occurs:

[image]

I would like it to be centred on the column.

**EDIT:**

I tried to use a tikz command from another question, but it does not work right:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tm}[2]{%
     \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};%
}

\newcommand{\DrawVLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[shorten <=0.3ex, #1] (#2.north) -- (#3.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\DrawHLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[shorten <=0.2em, #1] (#2.west) -- (#3.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\tm{topA}{3} & 3 & 1 \\
\tm{leftA}{1} & 0 & \tm{rightA}{^-4} \\
\tm{bottomA}{1} & ^-3 & 5
\end{array}
\right]
\DrawHLine[black, thick, opacity=0.5]{topA}{bottomA}
\DrawVLine[black, thick, opacity=0.5]{leftA}{rightA}
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with this? It seems pretty centered.

Comment: It is the strikeout on the first column I want to fix, as you see in the last image the strike hits the '3' in '3123123' but not the '1's in the second and third rows.

Comment: I suppose you could change `@{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}|@{\hspace{-.5\tabcolsep}}` to `@{\hspace{4.5\tabcolsep}}|@{\hspace{-3\tabcolsep}}`

Comment: I think the problem lies in \tabcolsep, being a specific number of characters, which would work, if I could get the largest number of characters in a certain column, and supply 1/2 that number to the \tabcolsep. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The `\colstrike` method proposed in @Werner's answer -- which he himself called "rudimentary" -- was only every meant to work with columns that contain single letters or numerals. For more general situations, you should look into employing one of the tikz-based methods proposed in the other answers.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196258/draw-a-vertical-line-over-the-entries-of-a-column-in-an-array

Comment: Simple, albeit manual, approach: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371657/cancel-package-and-tables

Comment: Does one of the links solved your problem? If not please add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that illustrates your problem. Starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I had a typo

Comment: The result you show in your last image is due to having run `pdflatex` just once. Whenever you use `\tikzmark`-like stuff (placing nodes with `remember picture,overlay`, and referencing those elsewhere) you have to run twice to get the correct output. In the first run the coordinates on the page are found and saved to the `aux` file, in the second run those coordinates can be used.

Answer (score 1):

The last code **does** work, you misplaced the commands `\DrawHLine` and `\DrawVLine` so the lines could not be orthogonal.

```
\DrawVLine[black, thick, opacity=0.5]{topA}{bottomA}
\DrawHLine[black, thick, opacity=0.5]{leftA}{rightA}
```

[image]